# how to place ELSE on if function on multipostthumbnails?

Tags: thumbnails

Hello guys I am making a featured images but i want IF to have Else, maybe this is an easy question but i am is suffer. I don't know how to change this function to have ELSE

```
    if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) :
    MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type());
    endif;
```

i need here to have

```
else{
 someimage
}
```

Comment: Try learning a bit more about PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Either**

```
if ( class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails') ) :
    MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type());
else:
    //someimage
endif;
```

**OR**

```
if ( class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails') ) {
    MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type());
} else {
    //someimage
}
```

**In regards to your comment:**

```
if ( class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails') ) :

    $image = MultiPostThumbnails::get_the_post_thumbnail( get_post_type(), 'secondary-image', NULL, 'proimg', array('class' => 'img-responsive imgwid') );

    if ( !empty( $image ) ) {
        echo $image;
    } else {
        echo '<p>asdasdasdasdasdas</p>';
    }
endif;
```

Comment: `<?php
if ( class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails') ) :
    MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image', NULL,'proimg',array('class' => 'img-responsive imgwid'));
else:
    echo'<p>asdasdasdasdasdas</p>';
endif;
?>`

Comment: This won't show the echo  if the Featured image is empty i don't know why